# Javascript namespace and public functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fine-uploader

I'm writing a jQuery plugin to allow the initializing of multiple, single file upload fields (using [Fine Uploader](http://fineuploader.com/)) in a specified form.

Ultimately I would like the form to know that it has these single uploaders attached to it, so I can run some validations, etc before manually starting the file uploads and submitting the form.

My ideal initialization code would look like this:

```
var form = $("form");
form.uploader();
form.addUploader({
  element: '.uploader_one'
});
form.addUploader({
  element: '.uploader_two'
});
```

So far the plugin I wrote to make this happen looks like:

```
(function($) {

    var Uploader = function(form){
       addUploader = function() {
          // Initialize Fine Uploader
       }

       $(form).submit(function(e) {
         // Run validations, then process uploaders
         $(this).submit();
       } 
    }

    $.fn.uploader = function(options) {
       var uploader = new Uploader(this);
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Most of this works, except that the addUploader function is not publicly accessible.

Might I be going about this the wrong way? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to make the `addUploader` a member of the object to make it accessible through the object (instead of as a global variable disconnected from the object):

```
 this.addUploader = function() {
```

The plugin has to do something with the object so that it becomes accessible, for expample returning it:

```
$.fn.uploader = function(options) {
  return new Uploader(this);
};
```

Now you can get the object from the plugin and use it:

```
var form = $("form");
var upl = form.uploader();
upl.addUploader({
  element: '.uploader_one'
});
upl.addUploader({
  element: '.uploader_two'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the general practice for developing plugins. A suggested structure for your plugin is something like:

```
(function($) {
    var methods = {
        init: function (options) {
            var data = $(this).data("uploader-plugin");
            if (!data) {
                $(this).on("submit", function (e) {

                });
                $(this).data("uploader-plugin", new Uploader(options));
            }
        },
        add: function (options) {
            // Use `options.element`
            $(this).data("uploader-plugin").elements.push(options.element);
            console.log($(this).data("uploader-plugin"));
        }
    };

    var Uploader = function (opts) {
        this.whatever = opts.a;
        this.elements = [];
    };

    $.fn.uploader = function(method) {
        var args = arguments;
        return this.each(function () {
            if (methods[method]) {
                return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(args, 1));
            } else if (typeof method === "object" || !method) {
                return methods.init.apply(this, args);
            } else {
                $.error("Method " +  method + " does not exist on jQuery.uploader");
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/WyGqc/

And you will call it like this:

```
var form = $("form");
form.uploader({
    a: "whatever";
});
form.uploader("add", {
    element: ".uploader_one"
});
```

It actually applies it to all selected elements from the original selector, and continues chaining. It also follows the normal convention for plugin use - meaning, you call the plugin name (`uploader`) with different parameters to do different things.